# Design principles in java

Tags: java, linked-list, queue

Why does the underlying source code of a java queue get its size by traversing rather than maintaining static variables? For example, linkedList tracks size through static variables and wants to know why it is designed.

Do not add entities unless necessary？

Comment: What `Queue` do you mean? `java.util.Queue` is an interface and doesn't have an implementation for the `size()` method and I couldn't find (in reasonable time) any implementation of that interface that calculates the size by traversing.

Comment: ConcurrentLinkedQueue

Answer (score 0):

This is likely the cost of holding/aquiring the value.

When you keep a static variable it costs memory and the time to keep the value up to date - while you still do not know whether you need the value at all.

In contrary you can calculate the value, e.g. by traversing the list. This will cost time.

So depending on the amount of data you store, the dynamics of insertion/deletion, how you need to access the data and how often you need the size one or the other implementation may be beneficial. That is why the platform offers many different collection types.

Comment: Why does linkedList do this?

Comment: From the perspective of resources, I agree with you. But I always feel strange

Comment: Imagine you have a few thousand entries in a linked list. How many read operations would it cost you to find out the size, unless you have a field for it?

Comment: In the case of large amount of data, the queue will have similar problems

Comment: What Queue do you mean? java.util.Queue is an interface and doesn't have an implementation...

Comment: Maybe I didn't describe it clearly. It should be the implementation of ConcurrentLinkedQueue, which has been roughly understood by now. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

The likely reason is the cost to update a `size` field.

`ConcurrentLinkedQueue` is written for high-performance concurrent `offer()` and `poll()` operations and is written trying to minimize contention for the same memory location.

Maintaining a `size` field would require updates to that field on every call to `offer()` and `poll()` and that update must be atomically (maybe using `AtomicLong` which under contention may need to loop several times until the value has been changed).

For a queue the size is normally less important than the simple "is empty" / "is not empty" property (and a similar "is full" / "is not full" - but for an effectively unlimited queue like `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` it is impossible to reach a "full" state).